# how to run/view the output of a subsection of code in eclipse (beginner)

Tags: eclipse

I am a complete beginner in java/eclipse/programming. I want to test small parts of my code to see if they are functioning in the way I want them to.

It is not intuitive to me from my first impressions of the program if/how I can run subsections of code. I also haven't yet found the answer to this problem online.

**1) In eclipse, is it possible to highlight a couple of lines of code and view the output they would produce in the console?**

**2) If so, what are the step by step instructions to do this?**

EDIT: I am running eclipse 4.7.0

Comment: Use the [Eclipse Debugger](http://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/june/article1.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a **`.jpage` *Scrapbook* page** (see Eclipse help: *[Creating a Java Scrapbook Page](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-create_scrapbook_page.htm)*):

[image]

(via https://twitter.com/EclipseJavaIDE/status/882560433588240384)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to keep your code modular or in other words make sure the different parts of your code are different functions. This way its simple to just run each function individually from your main function. In Java the main function is required so everything that you want to run has to somehow be triggered from whats in your main function.

Example in pseudo code:

```
some function{
    code you want to run
}

other function{
    other code you want to run
}

main function{
    some function()
    otherfunction()
}
```